# Can't find Database namespace in System.Data.Entity in ONE file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have no idea. I just created a Global.asax and I'm just trying to use System.Data.Entity.Database and it has no idea what I want.

```
using System;
using HROpenEnrollment.Model;
using System.Data.Entity;
using HROpenEnrollment.Data.EntityFramework;

namespace HROpenEnrollment
{
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        using System.Data.Entity.
    }
```

The irritating part is I can use it elsewhere. Here's another file in the same project that works fine.

```
using System;
using HROpenEnrollment.Model;
using System.Data.Entity;
using HROpenEnrollment.Data.EntityFramework;

namespace HROpenEnrollment.Data.EntityFramework
{
    public class Populate : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<OpenEnrollmentContext>
    {
```

What gives? I get all the way to System.Data.Entity but it won't find anything after that.

Comment: What is the exact error, and where does it happen?

Comment: The error is "The type or namespace name 'database' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" and it occurs System.Data.Entity.>>Database<< here

Comment: @proseidon - Are you sure you are using the correct case? I.e. `Database` instead of `database`.

Comment: Yes, I just copied the error wrong. It is definitely using the correct syntax. I use it in my other files just fine.

Comment: There isn't an error.  I think it is because nothing underneath the System.Data.Entity implements IDisposable which is why you can import the namespace, but not use it in a using statement.

Comment: It's not about the using statement. I just used that as an example. The *updated* issue is that NOTHING in the HROpenEnrollment can use System.Data.Entity.Database. Anything I create in HROpenEnrollment.Data can use it. Just not in HROpenEnrollment. Even changing the namespace from HROpenEnrollment to HROpenEnrollment.Data doesn't work. Intellisense doesn't think that there is a Database class in my System.Data.Entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed Entity Framework 5?  Having only version 4 of the System.Data.Entity dll will net you nothing.

Comment: I am not sure, but if I had the wrong version, then why would I be able to use System.Data.Entity.Database in my other files?

Comment: Because you can reference v4.0 by default in 2010.  Check what version you are running against and remove any 4.0 references.

Comment: This helped me find it. The other namespace was in a different project that had no reference to entity framework. thanks.